# window maximize not working with watir and phantomjs

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir-webdriver, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In one of my test case I am trying to maximize browser window like below:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.window.maximize
browser.goto my_url
browser.screenshot.save 'url.png'
```

But it won't able to maximize window. It still popup a mobile view in my screenshot. Due to which my all test cases are fail.

I am able to resize window using watir `resize_to` action.

```
browser.window.resize_to(x,y)
```

But it fails in some screen resolution. So I need `browser.window.maximize` to work.

**Environment :**

rails 4.1.7, 
ruby 2.1.2,
watir-webdriver 0.8.0,
phantomjs 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded `phantomjs 1.9.0` to `phantomjs 1.9.8` and `$browser.maximize` start working. I have added answer if some else also experiencing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Watir Webdriver the below code does instead of $browser.maximize

Try and let us know

```
width = $browser.execute_script("return screen.width;")
height = $browser.execute_script("return screen.height;")
$browser.driver.manage.window.move_to(0,0)
$browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to(width,height)
```

Comment: Thanks but I already mention. Window.resize working for me. Need to know why window.maximize not working in my case.